# Error encountered: OpenCV !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor' error

Tags: opencv, python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\faces-test.py", line 20, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-10658tfl\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

I am not able to get around the error above. The code below is used to capture frames from a video that I saved to my local and is used as a parameter to VideoCapture() function.
But when I run the code below, I encounter the error above

```
import numpy as numpy
import cv2
import pickle

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascades/data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascades/data/haarcascade_eye.xml')
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
recognizer.read("trainner.yml")

labels = {"person_name": 1}
with open("labels.pickle", 'rb') as f:
    og_labels = pickle.load(f)
    labels = {v: k for k, v in og_labels.items()}

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('C:\\My_Studies\\Python\\testing\\images\\mygeneratedvideo.avi')

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Comment: your video capture path should be 'C:/My_Studies/Python/testing/images/mygeneratedvideo.avi'

Comment: I still get the same error.

Comment: Simply what it is telling you is your path is wrong check the path for typos

Comment: What I have done now is, I have put the video file in the same folder where my source python file is. Still I am getting the error.

Comment: Any help would be really helpful  I have checked the ret value and it is returning True.

Comment: I met the same problem when loading image in VScode. I always restarted my computer and sometimes it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all other bits of code and try reading and displaying the video. After you get this working then worry about the rest of the code. Make sure you have the file in the specified folder and the name matches. Then try this:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('C:/My_Studies/Python/testing/images/mygeneratedvideo.avi')

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cv2.imshow("Output", gray)
    else:
        break
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Hi Fadi, I have done what you had told to do and the video opens up but then after the video closes, the same error is displayed again. I thank you a lot for your time. Just hoping that you can come up with some magic solution

Comment: This shows that your code works fine the only issue is when the end of the video is reached there is no frame to be converted to grayscale that is why you are getting the error.  To avoid this you have to break out of the capture loop when the video ends and return is 0. I have updated the code try the new code. Then you can add back the rest of your code.

Comment: Hi Fadi, I am very thankful to you for your time and advice. It worked.